C++ WebServer: Util (Pynt) Part-1
I think I made a mistake trying to start from the simplest version and working forward. This time I will present the final version, get all the fixes from here and incorperat them into the code, then I can reverse engineer the steps to get there.
Notes:

I am not looking at the HTTP part (I will have a separate set of articles on this). For this demo I am simply going to reply "Hello World" for all requests.

I am not going to look at handling command line argument or configuration (again another article to come on that).


The Parts of the server are:

NisseServer: Part-5
EventHandler: Part-4
Store: Part-3
JobQueue: Part-2
Pynt: Part-1

This post has some generics class definitions (and Pynt). The following articles will go over each of the above classes one at a time building up to the NisseServer class.
Note: I am using ThorsSocket a library I wrote that handles Sockets and Secure Sockets with a single wrapper class Socket and provides an std::iostream interface SocketStream. But has been written to work with cooperative multitasking libraries and will yield if an IO operation would block. This allows the user to write code that looks like normal synchronous code but will work like async code.
Thus the code to handle HTTP as described in this post look like normal code but is totally async with the threads yielding the Work object (and can be taken up by another thread).
NisseUtil.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_NISSE_UTIL_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_NISSE_UTIL_H

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
#include <boost/coroutine2/all.hpp>
#include <functional>

namespace TAS   = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket;

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{
/*
 * Forward declare Store objects.
 * See Store.h for details
 */
struct ServerData;
struct StreamData;

/*
 * Action to be performed by EventHandler
 * When the work code is blocked.
 * See EventHandler for details.
 */
enum class TaskYieldState        {RestoreRead, RestoreWrite, Remove};

/*
 * The types need to do the work.
 * Created by the Server object.
 */
using CoRoutine     = boost::coroutines2::coroutine<TaskYieldState>::pull_type;
using Yield         = boost::coroutines2::coroutine<TaskYieldState>::push_type;
using ServerTask    = std::function<void(ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server& stream, Yield& yield)>;
using StreamTask    = std::function<void(ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream& stream, Yield& yield)>;
using ServerCreator = std::function<CoRoutine(ServerData&)>;
using StreamCreator = std::function<CoRoutine(StreamData&)>;

}

#endif

Pynt.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_PYNT_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_PYNT_H

/*
 * Virtual base class for representing different protocols.
 *
 * You can add a Pynt to a port on a Nisse server.
 * Any connections that come to this port will result in a call to the 'handleRequest' method.
 *
 * The 'handleRequest' has a single parameter 'stream'.
 *  Reading from stream reads from the socket.
 *  Writing to the stream writes to the socket.
 *
 * Note: The stream is non blocking.
 *       If a read/write would block the thread will pause your code
 *       do something else and return to your code when the stream is OK to use again.
 *       Your code does not have to do anything special to handle this simply write the
 *       code as if the stream were blocking.
 *
 * Return:  PyntResult::Done    Indicates all communication is done and the server should close the socket.
 *          PyntResult::More    Indicates this request has completed but there may be another.
 *                              So keep the socket open to see if the client makes another request.
 *                              Example: HTTP with header 'Connection: keep-alive'
 */

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include "NisseUtil.h"
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{

enum class PyntResult {Done, More};

class Pynt
{
    public:
        virtual ~Pynt() {}
        virtual PyntResult handleRequest(TAS::SocketStream& stream)    = 0;
};

}

#endif

main.cpp
#include "NisseUtil.h"
#include "NisseServer.h"
#include "PyntHTTP.h"

#include <ThorsLogging/ThorsLogging.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ThorsLogging: Log level => 9 all messages (exceptions) displayed: Default std::cerr
    loguru::g_stderr_verbosity = 9;

    std::cout << "Nisse Server\n";

    int             port = 8080;
    if (argc > 1) {
        port = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    }

    // Note: Or create TAS::SServerInfo for secure socket.
    TAS::ServerInfo      initPort{port};

    // Set up the server
    ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseServer  server;

    // Processes HTTP connection on port.
    ThorsAnvil::Nisse::PyntHTTP     http;
    server.listen(initPort, http);

    // Run the server
    server.run();
}

